# WAMP & SendMail not working with GMAIL

Tags: php, smtp, gmail, wamp

I have scoured every tutorial out there on how to do this and I am still not getting the desired result so there must be some detail I am missing. The **mail()** function returns as though it succeeded however I NEVER GET ANY EMAILS in my sent or inbox

In a nutshell I have done the following:

1. Copied Sendmail.exe and Sendmail.ini along with their dlls to a
   folder named Sendmail that resides in c:\program files\wamp\bin\
2. Edited the sendmail.ini to point to port 465 (for gmail) and smtp to
   smtp.gmail.com, also configured the correct user name and password
   authentication fields, as well as set smtp_ssl to ssl
3. Enabled the php_openssl and php_sockets under php extensions in wamp
4. edited php.ini [mail function] parameters. I commented out everything in win32 and then set smtp_path = c:\program files\wamp\bin\sendmail\sendmail.exe -t" then restarted all serviced on WAMP
5. Logged into my gmail account and enabled IMAP

Can anyone please help me out here???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from : http://blog.techwheels.net/send-email-from-localhost-wamp-server-using-sendmail/

I followed the steps and was able to send emails from wamp server. Your problem seems to be the name of the folder "Program Files" it has a space in it.

> If the path to the sendmail.exe contains “space” (for example, “C:\Program Files\PHP\sendmail\”) then Apache would not be able to locate it. So, either store the sendmail.exe at a “non-spaced” location/path OR write the path in DOS style “C:\Progra~1\PHP\sendmail\” in the php.ini (sendmail_path = "C:\Progra~1\PHP\sendmail\sendmail.exe -t -i").

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at > http://phpmailer.worxware.com/?pg=examplebgmail

and https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer

It's a lot easier and it saves a lot of time to send using frameworks rather than attempting to tinker wamp on your own.

(on a side note, it's MUCH easier to send gmail via smtp with python)

Good luck!

Comment: Not quite the answer to my question but I tried your way and it is indeed much simpler. Plus I can re-deploy this which is nice